# how to select based on a substring in jq

Tags: json, select, jq, contains

With `jq`, how do I select only elements that contain the word "Star" in the following file `movies`:

```json
$ cat movies
[
  {
    "title": "Dark Knight, The",
    "year": 2008
  },
  {
    "title": "Star Trek Beyond",
    "year": 2016
  },
  {
    "title": "Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens",
    "year": 2015
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "title": "Star Trek Beyond",
  "year": 2016
}
{
  "title": "Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens",
  "year": 2015
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
jq '.[] | select(.title | contains("Star"))' movies
```

Comment: the manual [reference](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#contains(element))